# Unable to get all task from JBPM 6.4

Tags: task, jbpm, business-process-management

Is there a way to get all task and potential owners for each task from system? 
I found that there are some method on task service but it returns only a part of the tasks and without potential owners.

Comment: How exactly do you use jBPM? Do you use jBPM engine directly, KIE Workbench (jBPM Console) remote APIs or KIE Server? And which task service methods have you tried so far? Give us some more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my solution:

```
@Inject
TaskService taskService;

@Inject
@PersistenceUnit(unitName = "org.jbpm.domain")
private EntityManagerFactory emf;

EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();

final CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(TaskMinimal.class);
final Root taskRoot = criteriaQuery.from(TaskImpl.class);
final TypedQuery query = em.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<TaskMinimal> taskMinimals = query.getResultList();
List<Task> tasks = taskMinimals.stream()
                .map(minimal -> taskService.getTaskById(minimal.getId()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());



public class TaskMinimal {

     private long id;

     public TaskMinimal(long id){
        this.id = id;
     }

     public long getId() {
        return id;
     }

     public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check records in table PEOPLEASSIGNMENTS_POTOWNERS and table TASK in database. Do you have access to database or you have to get such information from Workbench or rest api ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use KIE-Server, there is a REST API that provide all of these.Simply go to :8180/kie-server/docs for all details.

Comment: I don't use KIE-Server